# Is there a better way to parse Youtube API XML than this?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, youtube

This is a fragment from my PHP youtube playlist API program and how I parsed the XML and saved the data in YoutubeVideo Objects. Is there a better way of parsing the XML than this? Note this needs to work with PHP 5+

-If you want to see the demo of the working code it is available at @ http://www.ericsicons.com/yt_playlistapi

-Source code is @ https://github.com/ericsicons/PHP-Youtube-Playlist-API-Plug-in

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' . $playlistID
        . '?max-results=50&start-index=' . $startIndex);
if (!$xml) {
    throw new PlaylistNotFound(".: Error Opening Playlist " . $this->getID()
    . ", Please check if the playlist ID is valid :.");
}

$t = $xml->children('openSearch', true);

$this->playList['title'] = (string) $xml->title;
$this->playList['description'] = (string) $xml->subtitle;
$this->playList['numVideos'] = (string) $t->totalResults;

$i = -1;
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    $i++;
    // YT XML elements references
    $media = $entry->children('media', true);
    $yt = $entry->children('yt', true);
    $gd = $entry->children('gd', true);

    /* Creating the Video Objects */
    $this->videoList[] = new YouTubeVideo();
    $t = $media->group->player->attributes();
    parse_str(parse_url($t['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $vars);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setId($vars['v']);
    $t = $media->group->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
    $this->videoList[$i]->setThumbnail($t['url']);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setTitle($media->group->title);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setDescription($media->group->description);
    $t = $media->group->content->attributes();
    $this->videoList[$i]->setDuration($t['duration']);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setDatePublished($entry->published);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setAuthor($entry->author->name);
    $t = $yt->statistics->attributes();
    $this->videoList[$i]->setViews($t['viewCount']);
    $this->videoList[$i]->setFavorites($t['favoriteCount']);
    $t = $gd->rating->attributes();
    $this->videoList[$i]->setNumRaters($t['numRaters']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a better way of parsing the XML. Not using SimpleXML would just make it worse.

It's out of the scope of the question, but currently you are using the RSS+XML output
from this URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/migoicons/uploads

While it might be easier to fetch and decode JSON instead of XML from the Youtube API.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/migoicons/uploads?v=2&alt=json

```
<?php
$json_playlist = file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/migoicons/uploads?v=2&alt=json');
$playlist = json_decode($json_playlist);
var_dump($playlist);
```

Keep in mind that Google provides a decent PHP client library to access the Youtube API.
You might find it at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about google's API but the whole point of this project is for me to practice. Is using the JSON feed faster as well or just easier? The script using URL https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/migoicons/uploads is another script, I updated the question to show the correct URL

Comment: Cool project! Found it on Github: https://github.com/ericsicons/PHP-YouTube-Playlist-API-Plug-in Please include the link in your question :) Keep up the good work. Nice piano playing!!